# Standard and official list of Coordinate Reference Systems

Tags: coordinate-system, standards

If there is a standard body defining official Coordinate Reference Systems, then where can we find the official list of codes and metadata for each of the CRSes?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) provides links including to OGC and refers to SRIDs, unclear whether this is the standard and where to find the list.

Comment: This https://epsg.org/home.html is the biggest and best known, but there are other authorities (IGNF, ESRI, NKG...) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [IOGP's EPSG geodetic registry](https://epsg.org/) whose EPSG codes are ubiquitous in the GIS world.  [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPSG_Geodetic_Parameter_Dataset).

Note: The EPSG geodetic registry was originally maintained by EPSG (European Petroleum Survey Group). That group was later subsumed into [IOGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Association_of_Oil_%26_Gas_Producers).

In the last several years, ISO (International Organization for Standardization) has their own [Geodetic Registry](https://geodetic.isotc211.org/) which has focused on geodetic coordinate reference systems (CRS) but has started adding projected CRS recently.

(Edited by mkennedy -- discloser: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG geodetic registry)

Comment: This is the official EPSG site: https://epsg.org/home.html